# При клике вне меню, закрывать его

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть такой вот код бургер-меню, как при клике вне меню, закрывать его?

```html
<div class="ng-cloak">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div id="nav-toggle" ng-click="toggleNav = !toggleNav; animate = !animate" ng-class="{'active': animate}">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <div class="menu-text-wrapper">
        <p class="menu-text only_desktop">MENU</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mobile-nav-menu" ng-show="toggleNav">
    <h5 id="burger_menu-title">Accounts</h5>
    <ul ng-click="close()">
      <li ng-repeat="item in departments">
        <a ng-click="getValueOfHref(item)">{{item.incDept}}<i
                      class="fa fa-chevron-right"
                      aria-hidden="true"
                    ></i
                  ></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a ng-href="#/logout">Logout<i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i
                  ></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для скрытия меню я использовал, скорее всего, самое плохое средство - уменьшение шрифта и отступов между элементами. Надеюсь, Вы располагаете готовой функцией скрытия меню (её надо будет вставить вместо `YourHideMenuFunction`, а `YourMenuId` - идентификатор скрываемой части).

```
var menu = document.getElementById("YourMenuId");
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target != menu) YourHideMenuFunction();
});
```

Думаю, это то, что Вам нужно: скрывать меню, если нажали не на него.